# 2013 impala brake lights

Tags: electrical

When I press my brake pedal when car is off the brake lights don’t come on. When I start the car the lights will come on when I hit the brake pedal. Is this normal or a problem I have never noticed this before

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

The brake lights are supplied by the ignition circuit so that they work when the engine is running or, more precisely, once the key is turned to ignition.